# Get id of element with a particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i want to get the id of an element with a particular class using jquery or javascript

this is the full code and a long one that leads to me getting undefined when i use the checkDet function.

```
<div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color: #fafafa; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;">
                <div class="p-property-start">
                <div class="p-property-item">


                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <p class="p-item-title">Color:</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <span class="p-item-main">
                        <ul class="colo-list">
                            <?php $notacol = DataDB::getInstance()->get_rows_from_field('product_color','product_id',$value);
                                    foreach($notacol as $col){
                            ?>
                                <li class="colo-list-image" id="col<?php echo $col['product_color_id']; ?>" onclick="selectColor<?php echo $col['product_color_id']; ?>()">
                                <a>
                                    <img src="img/product/icon/<?php echo $col['image']; ?>" title="<?php echo $col['color_name']; ?>">
                                </a>
                                </li>

<script>

function selectColor<?php echo $col['product_color_id']; ?>(){
var pro_col = <?php echo $col['product_color_id']; ?>;
var ins = 'prosi';
var d = document.getElementById("col<?php echo $col['product_color_id']; >");
$('.active').removeClass('active');
d.className += " active";


$.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: 'frextra.php',
        data: "pro_col=" + pro_col + "&ins=" + ins,
             success: function(data)
        {   
            document.getElementById("sizecover").style.display = "block";
            jQuery('#siz').html(data).show(); 
        }
    });

}           

</script>   
                            <?php } ?>

                        </ul>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>


                <div class="p-property-start" style="margin-top:50px; display:none;" id="sizecover">
                    <div class="p-property-item">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <p class="p-item-title">Size:</p>
                        </div>

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <span class="p-item-main">
                        <ul class="colo-list" id="siz">

                        </ul>
                    </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
<script>

function selectSize(ID){
var d = document.getElementById("siz"+ID);
$('.sactive').removeClass('sactive');
d.className += " sactive";
}           

</script>
                </div>

                <div class="p-property-start" style="margin-top:10px;">
                    <div class="p-property-item">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <p class="p-item-title">Quantity:</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">

                            <fieldset style="padding-top:10px;">
                                <input type="number" id="quantityfr" value="1">
                                <span style="color: #999;">Quantity left (594686 pieces available)</span>
                            <fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12 p-property-padd" style="padding-top:30px;">
                <div class="p-property-item">

                    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Add to cart" onclick="checkDet()" class="button biz-btn" style="font-size: 15px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 10px;">

                    <a onclick="saveWishlist()" class="add-wish" style="padding-left:20px; font-size:16px;">
                    <i class="fa fa-heart add-wish-heart" id="heart"></i>
                    <span>Add to wishlist</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                </div>

            </div>
<script>
   function checkDet(){
   var abc = $(this).closest("colo-list-image active").attr("id");
   console.log(abc);
   }
</script>
```

so basically what am doing is getting a product colors. when the user clicks in a color i fetch the sizes for that color. right now i want to know the id of the color selected by checking the color that is presently active in css

Comment: What does `this` refer to in `checkDet()`? How are you calling that function? Also note that `closest()` needs selector prefixes, so it should be `.closest(".colo-list-image.active").prop('id')`

Comment: $(this).closest(".colo-list-image.active").attr("id"); check dots.

Comment: Thanks for editing. The way you're calling `checkDet()` means that `this` willl be the `window`, not the element that raised the event. I'd suggest using a `click()` handler in jQuery instead of the outdated `on*` event attribute. Also, the `input` doesn't seem related to the previous HTML you posted, so I don't see how `closest()` will work either.

Comment: what do you suggest i do then @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Are you through foreach in php, adding the product id to col. right ? 
it's a bit hard to help you, since we don't know `where is the button`, and `which id's` you want.

You want id of all element with specific class ?

Comment: @nsikak could you please add a more complete HTML sample which shows how the `<input type="button">` elements relate to the `li` you want to amend

Answer (score -1):

This should work

Why don't you put $col['product_color_id'] as value on the tag img and do this

```
function FindClass(){
    $( "li" ).each(
        function(){
            if($(this).attr('class')=='colo-list-image active'){
                console.log($(this).find('ul').find('a').find('img').attr('value'));
            }
        }
    );
}
```

you can also save as an array

```
var arr = [];
function FindClass(){
    $( "li" ).each(
        function(){
            if($(this).attr('class')=='colo-list-image active'){
                arr.push($(this).find('ul').find('a').find('img').attr('value'));
            }
        }
    );
}
```

note that arr is outside the function so its a global variable, you can use whatever you want

Comment: `$(this).css('colo-list-image active')`?

Comment: At least it would now work logically, although it's still very brittle and a lot more longwinded than the OPs original which should already work in a much more succinct way. There is clearly another problem here which the OP has not given us details of.